# Multi-user RDS RemoteApp on same machine

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rds, remoteapp

I am running Server 2012R2 and have setup RDS Published RemoteApp's for the first time. So far everything is working fine when I launch an app with a particular user (using the .rdp shortcuts and type in the username). There is a particular use case for some software testers where they need to have 2 of the same RemoteApp's but for different users (a chat app). So far I have not had any luck with hard coding different username's in the .rdp file, the problem is when I click on the second .rdp file with the second username, it just brings the 1st RemoteApp to the foreground. Is this possible to configure?

Comment: Do you got an active directory ? As usually Single SignOn will make the job for the username/password, you usually dont need to hardcode the username/password.

Comment: I do have ADFS 3.0 yes but in this case, I want to have two RemoteApp sessions for 2 different users on the same client machine hence SSO would not improve this situation.

Comment: Yeah I copied the .rdp file so now I have 2 files on my desktop called 1.rdp and 2.rdp. Both files have the same contents except for the username; 1.rdp has DOMAIN\usera and 2.rdp has DOMAIN\userb. When I click on 1.rdp, the RemoteApp launches fine with usera logged on. However when I click 2.rpd, it just bring the first RemoteApp (usera) to the foreground, it does not launch another instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this working, I added `disableconnectionsharing:i:1` at the end of the .rdp file.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. You can accept your own answer, so it will be easier to find.